# Why APT can't locate GNURADIO package even though it apparently exists in repository?

Tags: raspbian, apt, gnuradio

I have been trying to install the GNURADIO package that is listed on the raspbian mirror:

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnuradio/

I've added the repo to my sources.list as below:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

After that I've been trying to run `sudo apt-get update` serveral times without any luck. `apt-get update` seemingly runs without error, but subsequent attempts to install GNURADIO fail:

```
pi@raspberrypi-2 ~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free 

deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
pi@raspberrypi-2 ~ $ sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host raspberrypi-2
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Sources [6,252 kB]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Get:2 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Sources [52.7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Sources [97.6 kB]
Hit http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Get:4 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages [23.3 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages [48.0 kB]
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en_GB                                           
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en                                              
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB                                              
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en                                                 
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_GB                                          
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en                                             
Fetched 5,513 kB in 34s (162 kB/s)                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done
pi@raspberrypi-2 ~ $ sudo apt-get install gnuradio
sudo: unable to resolve host raspberrypi-2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnuradio is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnuradio' has no installation candidate
pi@raspberrypi-2 ~ $ apt-cache search gnuradio
gnuradio-doc - GNU Software Defined Radio toolkit documentation
pi@raspberrypi-2 ~ $
```

Why can't APT find these packages? Is the repository corrupt? I saw a similar question posted here but it was resolved via an update, which doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be this: "sudo: unable to resolve host raspberrypi-2"

Comment: Well, I actually already fixed it. It was an un-related issue with the hosts file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gnuradio 3.7 packages you see at http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnuradio/ are not included in the index for wheezy. They are for jessie, so I suppose these packages are only available and built for [jessie](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Never read much into the index you speak of, but I'll take note for future reference. Once I added jessie to my sources.list and did and update I was able to access all gnuradio packages.

Comment: For posterity, WRT getting packages from Jessie: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can access the web, so you can download and install the `.deb` package yourself:

```
wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnuradio/gnuradio_3.7.0-5_armhf.deb
dpkg -i gnuradio_3.7.0-5_armhf.deb
```

Of course, you need to take care of dependencies first -- at least some of the libraries in that directory will be required too.  To find out what you need:

```
dpkg -I gnuradio_3.7.0-5_armhf.deb
```

The `-I` is actually for "information" (`-i` is for "install"), the part you want to pay attention to is `Depends:`

> Depends: python (>= 2.7), python (<< 2.8), python-opengl, python-lxml,
>   python-wxgtk2.8, python-cheetah, adduser, libasound2 (>= 1.0.16),
>   libboost-date-time1.54.0, libboost-filesystem1.54.0,
>   libboost-program-options1.54.0, libboost-system1.54.0,
>   libboost-test1.54.0, libboost-thread1.54.0, libc6 (>= 2.4), libcomedi0
>   (>= 0.8.1), libfftw3-single3, libgcc1 (>= 1:4.4.0),
>   libgnuradio-analog3.7.0, libgnuradio-atsc3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-audio3.7.0, libgnuradio-blocks3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-channels3.7.0, libgnuradio-comedi3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-digital3.7.0, libgnuradio-fcd3.7.0, libgnuradio-fec3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-fft3.7.0, libgnuradio-filter3.7.0, libgnuradio-noaa3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-pager3.7.0, libgnuradio-pmt3.7.0, libgnuradio-qtgui3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-runtime3.7.0, libgnuradio-trellis3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-uhd3.7.0, libgnuradio-video-sdl3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-vocoder3.7.0, libgnuradio-wavelet3.7.0,
>   libgnuradio-wxgui3.7.0, libgsl0ldbl (>= 1.9), libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13),
>   libiceutil35, libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) | libjack-0.116,
>   liblog4cpp5, liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.18), libportaudio2 (>=
>   19+svn20101113), libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.5.3),
>   libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3), libqwt5-qt4, libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11),
>   libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libuhd003, libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.8),
>   libvolk0.0.0 (= 3.7.0-5), libzeroc-ice35

You may not have quite a few of those, but you should be able to use `apt` for most of them since they will be accessible via `http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/`, except, obviously,  the `libgnuradio...` stuff.

Comment: I already started down the path of directly installing the DEBs, but I still want to know the answer to the original question. If we can clearly see and directly download the packages, then why can't APT see them in the repository?