# How can I access Raspbian Jessie packages from Wheezy?

Tags: raspbian, update, raspbian-jessie

I need a package that's in jessie, the newer version of Raspbian, but not in wheezy, the one I have installed.  Can I use it somehow?  Can/should I just upgrade to jessie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I use it somehow?

Maybe -- you can try.  Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list` and add a line:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main
```

Then run `apt-get update`.  This may take a few minutes. Searching for the package should now show it, and you can try `apt-get install [whatever]`.  You may have to pull in further substantial updates from jessie.

---

> Can/should I just upgrade to jessie?

You can *[as of Sept/2015, you probably should]*, but read the caveats below first.

First add the line as above above to `sources.list`, then:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You may also want to comment out the `wheezy` line from the `sources.list` above to prevent clutter or confusion in the future.

A few things to note about this:

- It requires a substantial download (1/2 GB+) and takes a while  in addition to that (perhaps a few hours), during which time you must occasionally answer questions.
- It changes the init system to [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), replacing the older [SysV init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SYSV).  You can install a compatibility package if this proves awkward.

Comment: I'd need to check but I think Raspbian has always defaulted to wheezy.  For most of that time wheezy was the testing release.  It has only recently become the stable release.

Comment: @joan Yeah, it rolls forward https://www.debian.org/releases/ Perhaps saying raspbian uses wheezy *because* it is stable is a bit of a simplification but hopefully it gets a point across.

Comment: I do use jessie/sid myself.  However as the Pi is used by a lot of newcomers to Linux I was a bit critical that Raspbian was originally based on the testing rather than the stable release.  I agree that using a stable release is the proper choice for the majority of users.

Comment: Raspbian started with wheezy because wheezy was the first Debian release to have arm hard float support. Tweaking the minimum CPU settings is a lot easier than adding hard float support from scratch.

Comment: The late release of a raspberry pi foundation raspbian jessie image was mostly down to difficulties forward porting the foundation's modified packages (most notablly their hacked up version of ephiphany)