# How to install emacs24.4 on a Raspberry Pi Model B+?

Tags: raspbian

I want the latest version of emacs to run on my raspberry pi.The raspberry pi runs raspbian and it seems that the repository only has version 23.4.1 which I can not use for it breaks the packages I use in emacs.So has anyone installed emacs24.4 on the raspberry pi successfully?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so a method you can try to install it, will be to compile it. To do this, follow the steps in terminal:

1. Download it from GNU: `wget http://gnu.mirrors.linux.ro/emacs/emacs-24.4.tar.gz`
2. Unzip:`tar -xzvf emacs-24.4.tar.gz`
3. Navigate to the unzipped directory
4. Type `./configure`
5. After the command from step 4 is done, type: `make`
6. Finally type in terminal: `sudo make install`

Somehow, what I described previously are the steps to compile & and install a software on Linux distributions from sources. Also, note that you'll can have some missing dependencies, to install it(emacs) you'll have also to install the dependencies but that can be done with `sudo apt-get install <dependency_name>` or by repeating the steps for each dependency.

Hope I could help you!

Answer (score 6):

Emacs 24.4 compiles and runs **perfectly** on the new Raspberry pi 2, using these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo libncurses5-dev
```

Install X related dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg8-dev libgif-dev libtiff5 libtiff5-dev
```

Run configure script:

```
./configure --prefix /opt/emacs
```

Add --without-x to the end of the configure command if you don't need X support.

Run make:

```
make
```

Check emacs binary was built and works:

```
./src/emacs
```

If Emacs loaded up alright, quit it and run make install:

```
make install
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Is it necessary to change to a specific folder (source) before running `./configure`? If so it should be mentioned to make this a complete advice.

Comment: Yes, you should run ./configure from the directory where emacs sources are...  the parameter --prefix /opt/emacs set up the directory where emacs will be installed. if is missing, the default location will be /usr/bin.

Comment: This mostly seems to work for emacs25.3 on raspbian stretch. There was some conflict between libjpeg8-dev and libtiff5 and libtiff5-dev that I didn't quite understand.

I was able to build and install 25.3 using your instructions but installing the various dependencies separately. It was also amusing to install something like libtiff... to see libjpeg's installation remove it, or something like that.

At the conclusion, I see installed: libtiff5 libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libjpeg-dev libjepg8 (but not libjpeg8-dev) 

emacs 25.3 is now installed on raspbian stretch, but not tested well

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use jessie which has emacs 24.4.1 in the repository.

```
harry ~ $ cat /etc/os-release  
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux jessie/sid"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
harry ~ $ emacs --v
GNU Emacs 24.4.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
harry ~ $
```

Comment: See: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy WRT installing jessie packages on raspbian wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to use `emacs` in the terminal, you may spare the trouble of installing GUI-related developmental packages by doing

```
tar -xzvf emacs-24.4.tar.gz
cd emacs-24.4
./configure --without-x
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes. I was able to install successfully**:

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.4.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $`

**Here are the steps**:

1) upgrade the apt-get:
`sudo apt-get update`

2) install emacs:
`sudo apt-get install emacs`

Comment: Is this using Raspbian Jessie, Stretch or Wheezy? If Jessie (or above), this seems pretty similar to [joan's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26918/58316) in terms of who it applies to.

Comment: This worked fine for me also on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 - sudo apt-get install emacs, thank you!