# how can I install php5-readline in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, php

how can I install php5-readline in raspbian? its not in the repos. And not in the debian repos with Wheezy arm support.

**Update:** November 2015

I abandoned Raspbian and moved to [Pidora](http://pidora.ca/), which seems to have solved all the issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could download the package (for later versions of Debian) from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5-readline , and then try and install that. This sometimes works, but may fail due to missing/outdated dependencies (dependencies are also linked on that page). You can install the packages using `dpkg -i FILE.deb` (you may also be able to use `gdebi FILE.deb`.

See also: [Dependency Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell), and [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy), but don't run `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: but that is for php 5.6, the php version in Raspbian is 5.4. :/

Answer (score 1):

`php5-readline` is now in the standard Raspbian repo for users running Jessie. It can be installed with the command, `sudo apt-get install php5-readline -y`.