# Which web-browser in Raspbian works best with GitHub?

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers, software-recommendation

Is there a web-browser for Raspbian that works with the GUI at https://github.com/? One should be able to create a repository with a license and create and edit files using the web GUI. I've tested most well known browsers already and they don't work for these tasks.

Comment: Iceweasel won't work for that?  Really?

Comment: I didn't test Iceweasel at first because Iceape doesn't work and they should be based on the same browser-code. Iceweasel works with GitHub but takes more RAM and I experienced once that it keeps running at full speed in the background after you shut it down. A more stable and less RAM-hungry alternative to Iceweasel, that works with GitHub, would be good.

Comment: Iceweasel should be pretty much [firefox with a different sticker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation_software_rebranded_by_the_Debian_project), version for version.  Iceape is a more obscure cousin.   I think the version of Iceweasel [in Jessie](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy) is slightly newer, I don't know if that will help with the unstable thing.  It probably won't with the memory thing....

Comment: ...512 MB is pretty tight for a GUI system + modern browser, all of which are hefty.  Most phones have a lot more than that now.

Answer (score 2):

What about Chromium?

To install type the following in the console:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

You could also try Iceweasel. (Haven't tested it yet but should probably work)

Comment: No, the current version of Chromium for Raspbian Wheezy doesn't work for GitHub on Raspberry Pi 1 B+, but Iceweasel does. I didn't test Iceweasel at first because Iceape doesn't work and they should be based on the same browser-code. Iceweasel works with GitHub but takes more RAM and I experienced once that it keeps running at full speed in the background after you shut it down. A more stable and less RAM-hungry alternative to Iceweasel would be good.