# Install latest version of a package

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, packages

I wanted to install Vim on my Raspberry Pi 2, but the repository only has v7.3 instead of the latest 7.4. There is some functionality missing in the old I need.

I've found that you can download the `.deb` directly, but I am not sure which architecture I should get. Also I won't get updates after that.

What would be the easiest way to get the latest version of this package?

Comment: There's a 7.4 [for Raspbian *jessie*](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vim/); note that's actually the wheezy and the jessie packages (hence a 7.3 and a 7.4 of everything).  You can try and download from there and install, they will be the correct architecture, or you can go the [more formal route](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy) and add jessie to your repo list, then just use `apt-get`...

Comment: ...I can't promise this will be possible, since if a jessie package has dependencies tracking to back to a newer libc, you need to upgrade the whole system to jessie.   When/if you get this to work, please leave an answer of your own.   One thing I strongly discourage anyone from doing is trying to compile vim from source, especially on the pi.   Not only is it big, but there are a number of very unfriendly complications involved.

Comment: @goldilocks Yes,   vi -v on Raspbian jessie on the Pi reports version 7.4.488.

Comment: @goldilocks You should make an answer out of that.

Comment: Yes, the dependencies are not recent enough. How unstable are the jessie packages?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run a copy of raspbian jessie, it's 10 days old. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=47944