# Networking issue after update to Jessie

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie, systemd

After updating from raspbian wheezy to raspbian jessie networking isn't working properly anymore.

Folllowing lines seem to describe the error:

```
ifplugd(eth0)[184]: Using interface eth0/B8:27:EB:0E:CD:AA with driver <smsc95xx> (version: 22-Aug-2005)
ifplugd(eth0)[184]: Using detection mode: SIOCETHTOOL
ifplugd(eth0)[184]: Initialization complete, link beat not detected.
ifplugd(lo)[203]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
ifplugd(lo)[203]: Using interface lo/00:00:00:00:00:00
ifplugd(lo)[203]: Using detection mode: SIOCETHTOOL
ifplugd(lo)[203]: Initialization complete, link beat detected.
ifplugd(lo)[203]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action lo up'.
ifplugd(lo)[203]: client: /sbin/ifup: failed to open lockfile /run/network/.ifstate.lock: No such file or directory
ifplugd(lo)[203]: client: run-parts: /etc/ifplugd/action.d//ifupdown exited with return code 1
```

But whats wrong, or what's the solution?

**Note**

This does not happen every time.

Could it be that *sometimes* our beloved systemd gets wrong its execution order? ...and then tries to start networking before /run/network/ is fully mounted or such a thing?!

Comment: I also had some problems with jessie, when I tried to connec to a DSL via NetworkManager. It seemed that it didn't work and because I didn't have time to search for a solution, I reinstalled wheezy. What can I say is that I think the problem is not just in the distribution for arm architecture. I had the problem on an i386...

Comment: So it would nice to hear from somebdy experienced with systemd...

Comment: *"Could it be that sometimes our beloved systemd gets wrong its execution order?"* -> More likely whoever configured the `ifplugd` service for Raspbian systemd screwed it up (ifplugd is not used by default on Debian or other regular distros).   If you don't want to bother investigating that, you could just uninstall ifplugd; its only purpose is to autoconfigure ethernet when you plug a cable into a headless system, and I suspect it is more a cause of grief than anything else (you don't need it to if you are booting a headless system with the cable already in).

Comment: You should probably also report this as a bug: https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs

Comment: Do you have any ifup rules?  i.e. /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ifupdown.rules

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'm considering reporting this as a bug - but first, I'm going back to wheezy so that I have a running system again. Maybe this will someday be fixed.

Comment: Perhaps that's why this goldilocks♦ guy said we shouldn't upgrade to Jessie unless we're really desperate. If you only wanted to install some packages from Jessie repository, refer to this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy

Comment: You should give Jessie another try. I tried it at the end of May, and systemd was sometimes keeping the CPU busy for nothing and the temperature of the CPU was raising, but that was the only problem. Anyway in one of the last package updates, this single problem got solved and in the last week Jessie run really stable. I only rebooted the Pi due to firmware update. *Note: I don't use the Pi as a desktop computer, but just as a network device (without any GUI).*

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and could solve it by upgrading to *NetworkManager*:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Then, disable all entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` since this gets replaced by *NetworkManager*.

In my case I did not even need to configure the *NetworkManager* by `nmcli` because my LAN connection was automatically detected and configured after reboot.