# Update MATE Desktop Environment on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

How can I update MATE with the version on this

https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMate

I want to update the MATE 1.6 version on the above version to the latest MATE 1.8.

Do I have to reinstall it, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

[Looking here](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mate-desktop-environment/), it seems the only version of MATE in the Raspbian repositories currently *is* 1.8,<sup>1</sup> and that their own web page is not up to date.

First, make sure the local records are up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try `apt-cache showpkg mate-desktop`.  If you get nothing, see the footnote.  If you get some information including:

```
Versions: 
1.8.1+dfsg1-2
```

You should be good to go.  You could try:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade mate-desktop
```

Note there are a bunch of packages involved in the desktop and this may or may not update all of them.  I recommend you just:

```
apt-get update
```

Which will do the whole system.  This may take a while; you may also run into complications if you've added `jessie` to your repo as per the footnote but not done a `dist-upgrade`.

---

1. But it does not seem to be on the package list for Raspbian wheezy; if I try `apt-cache search mate-desktop` on a wheezy pi I actually get nothing (hmmph...).  It shows up on a jessie pi, though.  You may not have to dist-upgrade but I think you likely will, see *[How can I access Raspbian Jessie packages from Wheezy?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26041/5538)*

Comment: Is a `apt-get dist-upgrade` needed for this?

Comment: @Bex I think probably it would -- missed that point before.  I've added a footnote and some other details about this.