# Cannot install code blocks on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, c++

I can't install code block: sources.list got like this:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free r$
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Installing:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package codeblocks is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  codeblocks-common

E: Package 'codeblocks' has no installation candidate
```

codeblocks-common doesn't works too

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install codeblocks-common`

Comment: Already typed that have tried

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get update` first to update the repositories and lists of packages and it's versions.
I just tried to install it and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Debian's package manager can be a surly PITA.  There may well be a way to untangle this properly, but in lieu of that here's something you can try.

There is certainly a ton of stuff in [the codeblocks directory of the Raspbian repo](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/codeblocks/), including what looks like v. 10.05 and 13.12 (note I'm not actually a codeblocks user).  These are respectively [the wheezy and jessie defaults](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=codeblocks).  So unless you want to [upgrade to jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy), you should try 10.05.  You want the `.deb` file:

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/codeblocks/codeblocks_10.05-2.1_armhf.deb
```

This can then be installed directly with `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -i codeblocks_10.05-2.1_armhf.deb
```

I'm not promising that won't spit the same error, but I think it might not.  It might instead fail because of a missing dependency, which you should try and install manually with `apt-get` and only if that fails start poking around in the repo as above.  Keep track of anything you do install with `dpkg`, because if it doesn't work in the end you should probably remove all that stuff:

```
dpkg -r codeblocks_10.05-2.1_armhf
```

Note that's the name of the package sans the `.deb` file suffix this time.  Dpkg has a manual page, see `man dpkg`.

Comment: I notice the last part of the first line of your `sources.list` is `r$`.  I don't know whether that was a cut and paste accident or if it really is that way, but it should be `rpi`.

Comment: It's just the way nano shows when text is longer than console.

Comment: I've added deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free and it worked, but I'm not sure either this do the job or sth else.