# how to swap dbus versions in rpi/linux?

Tags: pi-2, linux, rpi-update, version-control

DBus version installed: 1.10.6
Programs look at 1.1.1.
How to get rpi to look at newest DBus?

```
RPI Project/programs: alertR Home Alert System via github.
Current status:
12/30/2015 14:26:08 INFO: [alertRinstaller.py]: Checking the dependencies. 
12/30/2015 14:26:08 INFO: [alertRinstaller.py]: Checking module 'dbus'. 
The needed version '1.2.0' of module 'dbus' is not satisfied (you have version '1.1.1' installed). Please update your installed version.
```

Answer (score 1):

That check is for the python dbus module not for the version of the dbus daemon.

On Raspbian Jessie, version 1.2.0 is installed. I don't have Wheezy on anything to check what it has.  You should be able to uninstall the default version and replace it with the latest:

http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/

http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/dbus-python/

Comment: Yeah -- the `python3-dbus` package [on wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3-dbus&searchon=all&suite=oldstable&section=all) is 1.1.1.  [See here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26041/5538) about trying to upgrade the package, but as noted there at this point you should probably just upgrade the whole system unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for this. Followed above guidance but no luck. Still get: The needed version '1.2.0' of module 'dbus' is not satisfied (you have version '1.1.1' installed).
Please update your installed version.
New to RPI/linux etc... How to upgrade whole system? Purge first? Can you give me some command line prompts? Thanks!