# The following packages have been kept back: mopidy

Tags: raspbian, python, apt, packages

After performing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, I got the message

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  mopidy
```

What I usually do in this case, is `sudo apt-get install mopidy`. This resulted in the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   mopidy : Depends: python:any (< 2.8) but it is not installable
            Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~) but it is not installable
```

Is there some way to upgrade mopidy? I've checked, but Python is already at the latest version...

Comment: What is the output of `python -V`? <- Beware capital V.

Comment: @goldilocks: Python 2.7.3

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26041/5538) and see if it solves your problem (if so, please leave your own answer here).  If you are using wheezy (`cat /etc/issue` will refer to version 7, not 8), I recommend you upgrade the whole system (although you may not have to to upgrade python).

Comment: @goldilocks, https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/debian/ claims that mopidy comes in packages for wheezy and jessie. But does the above errors not suggest something from with dependencies - python (for whatever reason)?

Comment: Well, [here is the raspbian repo for python2.7](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/python2.7/) (notice .3, .9, .11 at the bottom for wheezy, jessie, stretch respectively).  You can *try* and install whatever you wish by whatever means you wish, but unless you are sure of what you are doing you should take `apt` seriously.  If the default on wheezy is 2.7.3, then it's mopidy's mistake.

Comment: @goldilocks: that explains it. I've still got wheezy, which has python 2.3.7, but mopidy's package (for wheezy) requires python 2.7. I'll drop them a line, and will attempt to get my pi on jessie tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @Martijn you mean "I've still got wheezy, which has python **2.7.3**, but mopidy's package (for wheezy) requires python **2.7.5**" don't you?

Comment: @SlySven: ack! You're right, I forgot the crucial **.5** there, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of the Mopidy core developers and the one packaging Mopidy for Debian.

It looks like you're trying to install the Mopidy Debian package as built for Debian jessie (stable) on a wheezy system (oldstable).

Please visit https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/debian/ and follow the instructions for wheezy. You'll then get packages built on and for wheezy, which works with the Python 2.7 version you already have.

Comment: That's odd, I haven't done anything at all (yet) in order to get jessie (I wasn't even aware that it was available till I read @goldilocks' comment on this question. **cat /etc/issue** gives ‛Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l‛.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Apparently I was still using raspbian's packages for mopidy, not mopidy's own.

Comment: If you already used Raspbian's packages for Mopidy they should match the Raspbian version you have. If you used Mopidy's own packages (which are really the same, but newer) you probably had "stable" as the dist in /etc/sources.list.d/mopidy.list. With the release of jessie last April the meaning of "stable" changed from wheezy to jessie, and you started getting the wrong set of packages.

Comment: That's the puzzling thing, AFAIR I _was_ using Raspbian's packages for Mopidy. I run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` at least once a month, and suddenly it gave me this error message.

Comment: Mopidy doesn't exist in Raspbian wheezy and hasn't had any upgrades in Raspbian jessie since jessie was released in April 2015. However, I uploaded a Debian package of Mopidy 1.1.2 to apt.mopidy.com a few days ago. Sounds like you already used apt.mopidy.com :-)

Comment: Ah, that would explain things, then. I have no memory of adding the mopidy packages, but forgetting that's not an unlikely scenario, either. Apologies for the trouble, and thanks for the help!