# Remote develeopment with Netbeans: debugger goes to disasembly

Tags: remote, c++, debug

I managed to [set up](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/compilers-and-ides/netbeans-windows/creating-a-new-project) remote development on RPi with Netbeans 8.0.2 over [direct connection](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection) to my laptop.
my simple program compiled, run and debugged.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout<<"hello Raspberry Pi";
    int e=8;//to see something in variables view
    return 0;
}
```

I was satisfied with the result, but default RPi compiler  is quite old (version 4.6.3) and does not support C++ 11, so I upgraded gcc and g++ to 4.8.2 and changed the links in `/usr/bin`.
That solved the problem with `-std=c++11` not being recognized.

But then another problem arose: while it the code still compiles and runs normally, it can no more be properly debugged: stepping through the code does not work, the debugger goes to disassembly instead, the breakpoint is ignored and the variables view is empty.
May be I need to upgrade anything else?
here is output of Netbeans build

```text
Copying project files to /home/netbeans/.netbeans/remote/192.1.2.200/andrey-laptop-Windows-x86_64 at netbeans@192.1.2.200
Building project files list...
Checking directory structure...
Checking previously uploaded files...
Checking links...
Uploading changed files:
    Zipping 1 changed files...
    Uploading zip to netbeans@192.1.2.200...
    Unzipping changed files...
Checking exec permissions...
Uploading changed files finished successfully.

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/netbeans/.netbeans/remote/192.1.2.200/andrey-laptop-Windows-x86_64/C/Doc/NetBeansProjects/HelloRPi'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellorpi
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/netbeans/.netbeans/remote/192.1.2.200/andrey-laptop-Windows-x86_64/C/Doc/NetBeansProjects/HelloRPi'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d"
g++    -c -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hellorpi build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/netbeans/.netbeans/remote/192.1.2.200/andrey-laptop-Windows-x86_64/C/Doc/NetBeansProjects/HelloRPi'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/netbeans/.netbeans/remote/192.1.2.200/andrey-laptop-Windows-x86_64/C/Doc/NetBeansProjects/HelloRPi'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
```

Comment: I'm not a netbeans user but WRT "so I upgraded gcc and g++ to 4.8.2" -- why don't you just upgrade to Raspbian jessie?  Sooner or later it has to happen.  **4.9.2 is the default there.**  Also, I would look and see if there is a way to configure netbeans to use a specific compiler before rearranging links, but sometimes a hack is the only solution.  Of course if the default is 4.9.2 it won't matter...

Comment: [upgraded](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) to no effect

Comment: That's just updating software in the current distro release -- you are obviously using Raspbian/Debian version 7, aka "wheezy".  The current version (as of spring 2015) is version 8, aka "jessie".  [See here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26041/5538) about upgrading to that.  You can tell the difference by looking at `/etc/issue`.

Comment: Ok upgraded the system. g++ got upfraded to 4.9 and gdb to 7.7 . And it didnt help. However I managed to find out something:  when i start debug and try to run to the cursor, the netbeans shows message: _No source file named /home/netbeans/.netbeans/remote/192.1.2.200/andrey-laptop-Windows-x86_64/C/Doc/NetBeansProjects/HelloRPi/main.cpp._

Comment: I created a new project, copied the source code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile a compiler by hand with CFLAGS "-g -ggdb" and compile the GDB itself too, use last versions. I've faced same problem in different circumstances, but IDE restored it's normal debugging abilities after a recompile cycle I've mentioned upstrings. And - when you're replacing something in Debian systems - make **SURE** that you're using `update-alternatives` script, **not just simple replacement**