# Can't install rpi-chromium-mods from pixel upgrade

Tags: update, pixel

I have a Pi 2 that has been kept current with the latest Raspian. I am trying to install the Pixel update that was [posted on the Raspberry Pi blog this morning](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/). Here are the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
sudo apt-get install -y rpi-chromium-mods  
sudo apt-get install -y python-sense-emu python3-sense-emu  
sudo apt-get install -y python-sense-emu-doc realvnc-vnc-viewer
```

The first two commands appear to execute correctly. Line 3, installing the chromium piece, fails, as it cannot find rpi-chromium-mods.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. I am on Wheezy, not Jessie. Which raises the question: Can Pixel be installed on top of Wheezy? Many Pi2 users may have never upgraded.

Comment: Possibly but probably not.  See: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26041/5538 However, beware that if you run `dist-upgrade` after editing `jessie` into `sources.list` (which I guess you may have to), you will be upgrading the whole system.

Answer (score 3):

On September 28, 2016, Simon Long presented in the official Rasperri Pi blog a beautification of the GUI for the Raspian distro (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/) called PIXEL (“Pi Improved Xwindows Environment, Lightweight”). He also explained how to update an existing Raspian Jessie installation:

> sudo apt-get update 
>   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
>   sudo apt-get install -y rpi-chromium-mods 
>   [...]

I followed the instructions exactly but got stuck at the 3rd statement:

> $ sudo apt-get install -y rpi-chromium-mods 
>   Reading package lists... Done 
>   Building dependency tree 
>   Reading state information... Done 
>   E: Unable to locate package rpi-chromium-mods

Thanks to Simon's support I could fix the problem by appending "**ui**" as component to all Apt lines found in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list:

> deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main **ui**

After having edited the file, I resynchronized my repos ( `sudo apt-get update` ) and the rpi-chromium-mods package installed successfully ( `sudo apt-get install -y rpi-chromium-mods` ).

Comment: Although this wasn't really a direct answer to the question, I think it should stand as confirmation of the issue, since you both seem to have followed the instructions in the blog.  I did not look through the comments but that might be worthwhile for further confirmation.

Comment: Sorry for posting an "answer" rather than a "comment". I also want to clarify that I'm on Jessie and not on Wheezy.

Comment: See Barbecue Joe's recent comment on the question.  Are you still using Wheezy too?

Comment: Ok, my problem is solved. It turned out that "ui" must be added to all lines found in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list - see also  https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/#comment-1264036

Comment: If you'd like to edit that into your answer it may be appreciated by others ;)

Comment: I agree - done.